# Undo community wiki on this question

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

[This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/496/how-can-i-get-involved-with-open-source-game-projects) *should not* be a community wiki question.

Generally there's not an over-doing it in terms of setting questions as community wiki, but I always go by for answers require a lot of information/expertise, not simply "Oh I loved [Excitebike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitebike) for the NES", then that is NOT community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, I agree, CW has been removed.

Comment: Can also un-community wiki the answers?

Comment: Since it won't stop alerting me until I respond. I did this.